# SQL query from minus to join

Tags: sql, join

How can I translate the following query:

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table1
minus
select col1,col2,col3 from table2
```

into a query that uses a join clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3
where t2.col1 is null
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a29d3/3)